# printing only filled data from JTable with logo

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, rowfilter

my program hava a JTable with 100 blank rows. 
Let user fills only 10 rows. Now he want to print only the filled rows with a logo on the top.
How to do it ?

Here is the code i used:

```
if(e.getSource() == print){
    try {
        table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, head, null); 
    } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e1) {
         System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e1.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

It simply prints all the 100 rows.

I want to print only the filled rows( let first 10 rows get filled)

Comment: how about check if the rows are filled, if yes then printout the data?

Comment: can u please post the code.

Comment: Did you wrote code to print the rows of the table? If so, post it.

Comment: u just do the `for` loop for 10 rows. and then `table.getValueAt(row, column).toString();` check if this `.equals("")` show what have you done so far

Comment: _can u please post the code_ that's not how this site works: typically, it's _you_ who must write _your_ code to solve _your_ problem. You'll bet help on the parts you are stuck with. If you don't know how to loop over the values of a table, you should take some steps back and read up on some basics (language features like loops and/or class specific api like JTable)

Comment: ok.. now i posted the code..

Answer (score 2):

you can filter the empty rows before printing:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
RowFilter filter = new RowFilter() {

    public void include(Entry entry) {
        // here add a loop which checks if 
        // any of the values in the entry is not-null
        // return true if yes, false otherwise (that is all empty)
    }
};
((DefaultRowSorter) table.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(filter);
table.print(....);
```